# how does ps4 (new) slim controller connect to system?

Tags: ps4

Been wondering how all gaming controllers connect to system in general , do they use IR blasters or is it something like Bluetooth?

Comment: Note: IR is a terrible way to control games. It requires direct line of sight between controller and console, which is easily disrupted. It works for TV remotes, because it really doesn't matter if it takes 3 seconds for the TV to notice the signal. For games, you want inputs to reach the console *reliably* within 30-50 milliseconds (0.03 - 0.05 seconds). IR is not suitable for this.

Answer (score 1):

The Playstation [Dualshock 3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DualShock#DualShock_3) uses Bluetooth and the [Dualshock 4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DualShock#DualShock_4) uses Bluetooth v2.1+EDR.